# C++ pointers vs std::vector: any implication for long size variables?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a C background and I am recoding some old code in C++...
In the process, I am starting to use C++ Vectors, which are so easy to use!

Would vectors deal well with very long streams of data? For example, in audio apps, loading a stereo 3 minutes song would need almost 16M floats

```
float *stereoSong = NULL;
stereoSong = new floats[15787800];
```

Not having to deal with memory management with vectors is very nice, but I was wondering if that huge amount of data would be handled well by C++ vectors

Thanks!

Comment: 20 million items of data is a lot.  Performance concerns would have to be in context of how that data is used.  Maybe an SQL backing store would be more appropriate, with windowing in portions of the data at a time.  Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: the motto is: as good as handwritten code, ie you can do with a `std::vector` what you can do with a dynamic c-array, if not then we would have a problem

Comment: `std::vector` is just an array in the heap with a size and a pointer to first element. Only performance problem I could think is that capacity increases by a factor of 2 every time it expands. This can be solved though with `std::vector::reserve` and even `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: Since you already know C, you can compare it to a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that a `std::vector` is just a pointer, and an element count (and one additional counter). The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nonsense. Automatic resizing, capacity management, an iterator facade, utility functions for manipulating the container... not "the end" at all.

Comment: I wrote an answer before this was unceremoniously closed. Here's a noddy program that gives a very big vector a run out. https://ideone.com/A6GmvQ. That code is even simplistic enough to not reserve capacity but allow the `std::vector` to do it.

Comment: @Persixty, I saw your answer late. I am new to this community so I got confused about the thread closing and re-opening. Your example is very useful

I did a quick test https://ideone.com/ycvBoB where I create and delete 200M of doubles using pointers and vectors
Both are very fast, but the pointer is slightly faster in my test.
Vectors are also fast though

Comment: @WewillSee 'Hardcore' the pointer will outperform `std::vector<>` because it is managing capacity behind the scenes. Even if you `reserve()` enough capacity, it's still checking! But your experience is common. good implementations of `std::vector<>` are so good you very rarely need to deal with a `raw` array.

Comment: @WewillSee PS: I voted to re-open. Some users are just too keen to close questions because they're not fully determined with a single 'right' answer. It's just unhelpful because there are useful answers to many of them. You got a useful answer so point proven.

Comment: @WewillSee Hi. I just noticed an error in your vector version `pointer2[i]=pointer2[i]`. You've assign pointer2 to itself. The optimiser has ignored that whole loop. When I run it the vector version is actually a touch faster though this isn't a scientific test!

Comment: Nice one @Persixty! Yes, that made a big difference and makes things even more clear  
That made me thinking about 2D vectors and the best way to use them in a class structure from a memory and performance management point of view.

Comment: So, in the class definition to add this variable:  `std::vector<std::vector<double>> vector_2D;`

And, in the class constructor  `vector_2D(numRows)` and loop over numRows to add each row `vector_2D[i] = std::vector<double>(numCols)`

Is that better than using a push_back each time we want to add a new row to t vector_2D?

_Note: still learning how to use comments and markdown properly_

Comment: @WewillSee There's a bunch of tweaks here. Initialising or setting size will construct 'empty' vectors. using `reserve()` will reserve space and not construct empty objects to be overwritten. You can use `emplace_back()` that avoid all copying because the vector is first constructed in place.  
Not guaranteed but all good implementations do that. Though you'll find the difference marginal. You should also start using ranged-for and iterators instead if integers. They are neater, faster and recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a false comparison.

For a start, vectors use pointers. They have to. Vectors are containers that use dynamic allocation to provide you with a buffer of data items. You could try to implement the same thing "with pointers", but you'd end up with something someway between a vector, and a worse version of vector.

So, vectors can handle as much data as you'd be able to handle with `new double[]` — that is, a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The answer very much depends on your platform.
You're talking about just over 150 MiB of data (a `double` is 8 bytes on practically all modern platforms).
This code has no trouble on a 'toy' environment (https://ideone.com/A6GmvQ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void build(std::vector<double>& data, const size_t size){
    void* ptr{data.data()};
    for(size_t i{1};i<=size;++i){
        data.push_back(2*i);
        if(data.data()!=ptr){
            ptr=data.data();
            std::cout << i << ' ' << ptr << ' ' << data.capacity() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t size{100000000L};
    
    std::cout << ((size*sizeof(double))/1024/1024) << " MiB" << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<double> data{};
    
    build(data,size);
    
    double sum{0};
    for(auto curr : data){
        sum+=curr;
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is knowingly dumb and doesn't even try to reserve capacity for the values (which can help) because `std::vector<>` helps with that anyway.

Behind the scenes the vector allocates a block of capacity and then re-allocates another larger capacity when the logical size of the vector exceeds the capacity.
The code 'watches' the internal representation and outputs each re-allocation...

There are members for you to help with that capacity management if you're consuming the values as a stream (which sounds likely for audio).

The short answer is 'give it a go'. I've cranked that up to 100M doubles and have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector`and co. were one of the reasons I changed form `C` to `C++`.

It takes all the management boilerplate out of array management.

When I need to resize an array allocation I would have to do the following

1. allocate new memory
2. copy the elements over
3. delete the old memory

Also all lifetime management is handled by the `std::vector` no more messing around with `delete` at the end of the lifetime, makes handling multiple exit points in a function much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The limit due to the implementation is [`std::vector::max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size). For example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/91nYEj) `std::vector<float>::max_size()` is `2305843009213693951`.

However, thats just the theoretical limit due to constraints of the implementation. Much sooner than that you will hit the memory limit of your hardware.

A `std::vector<float>` does not use (substantially) more memory than a dynamic c-array.